# How to properly use javascript with SUBMIT?

Tags: javascript, dom

At one point in the last 24 hours, I had a working function called get_contact_info which returned the contents of a series of text inputs.
Suddenly the code stopped returning the values and began returning "undefined" as the element values, though noting had been changed in the code or html.

custom.js contains the following

```
var first_name, last_name, email, phone_number;
var contact_info = [];

function get_contact_info(){
    alert("This is the function called by the button");
}
/*  contact_info[0] = document.getElementsByName('fname').value;
    contact_info[1] = document.getElementsByName('lname').value;
    contact_info[2] = document.getElementsByName('email').value;
    contact_info[3] = document.getElementsByName('phone').value;

    alert("Name = " + contact_info[0] + " " + contact_info[1]);
    alert("Email = " + contact_info[2] + ", Phone Number " + contact_info[3]);
};*/


}());
```

My html is the following:

```
        <form>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr><div class="custom text" style="color: red"><strong>Please enter your contact info to create a quote</strong></div></tr>
                <tr><td></td></tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>First Name:</strong></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="fname" value="Joe"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>Last Name:</strong></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="lname" value="Johnson"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>Email:</strong></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="email" value="joe@johnson.com"/></td>                        
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>Phone Number:</strong></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="phone" size="15" value="555-1212"/></td>     
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td><input id="contact_info" type="submit" value="Set My Contact Info" onClick="get_contact_info()" /></td>                     
                </tr>
            </tbody>                
        </table>
    </form>
```

Am I implementing this incorretly?
I am attempting to teach myself basic javascript but I seem to be failing on this piece and don't see where.

Using Firebug in Firefox v30.0, a console call to
    document.getElementsByName('fname').value;
returns "undefined"
    document.getElementsByName('fname');
returns a NodeList, but no elements.

*sigh*

Comment: `document.getElementsByName` --- what do you think this function does? And why do you think it should work for you?

Comment: Is the problem that the code is commented out?

Comment: document.getElementsByName should return all elements with the name  attribute as defined. It should work because I have an element defined as 'fname'.

Comment: I commented the code to see if I could get a simple alert to fire.

Comment: @KenIngram Have you read your answers yet? you do NOT have the name attributes defined.

Comment: Oh. I see what you did there zerkms.
I don't have a name set in my html. I have ID. 
Doh!

Comment: @KenIngram you defined `id` not `name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted has syntax errors, and the part that seems to be throwing an error is commented out. As others have said, you have a problem with *getElementsByName* and *getElementById*. But your issues go further than that.

A form can be submitted without clicking the submit button, so it's usual to attach listeners that should run when the form is submitted to the form's submit handler. It also helps to pass a reference to the form using *this* (the reason will become clear later):

```
<form onsubmit="get_contact_info(this)" ...>
```

Form controls are only submitted if they have a name, giving them an ID is usually unnecessary, so change the IDs to names:

```
  <td><input type="text" name="fname" value="Joe"></td>
```

And the submit button becomes:

```
<input type="submit" value="Set My Contact Info">
```

Now you also have a very convenient way to access the form controls using their name as properties of the form. Since a reference to the form was passed in the call (see above), the function can be:

```
var contact_info = [];

function get_contact_info(form) {
  contact_info[0] = form.fname.value;
  contact_info[1] = form.lname.value;
  contact_info[2] = form.email.value;
  contact_info[3] = form.phone.value;

  alert("Name = " + contact_info[0] + " " + contact_info[1]);
  alert("Email = " + contact_info[2] + ", Phone Number " + contact_info[3]);
}
```

Also note that [*getElementsByName*](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#dom-document-getelementsbyname) returns a [*live NodeList*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-536297177) that doesn't have a *value* property, so if you were going to use it, you'd use it like:

```
document.getElementsByName('email')[0].value
```

You could also create the array using an array literal:

```
contact_info = [form.fname.value, form.lname.value, form.email.value, form.phone.value];
```

Answer (score 2):

Use getelementbyidID not name, or set the name attribute.

```
contact_info[0] = document.getElementByID('fname').value;
```

Comment: Thanks.
Rookie move. Writing code with little sleep, no nourishment and frustrated.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `getElementsByName` instead of `getElementById` which will not work given that you never provided any `name` attributes for the inputs

```
contact_info[0] = document.getElementById('fname').value;
contact_info[1] = document.getElementById('lname').value;
contact_info[2] = document.getElementById('email').value;
contact_info[3] = document.getElementById('phone').value;
```